# Cannot show print dialog on the top of asp.net web control

Tags: printdialog

I am currently using System.Windows.Forms.**PrintDialog** on a custom control in ASP.net because I want to show the print dialog and assign its PrinterSettings to **ReportPrintDocument.PrinterSettings** after I click Ok button on the dialog.
Here is my code:

```
using (PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog())
                {
                   if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        ReportPrintDocument rp = new ReportPrintDocument(rvPermit.ServerReport);
                        rp.PrinterSettings = printDialog.PrinterSettings;
                        rp.Print();
                    }
                }
```

My problem is that the print dialog always show behind the web browser and I couldn't know that it is showing or not until I minimize the web browser.

Do you know how to show the print dialog on the top of a web form? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for now. (Not recommended)
If you can find another one, please share it to me and I'm very appreciate your help on that.

1. initialize a new window form 
   `Form currentForm = new Form();`
2. show the form
   `currentForm.Show();`
3. Activate the form
   `currentForm.Activate();`
4. Set its TopMost to true, so it will bring the form to the top
   `currentForm.TopMost = true;`
5. Set it to be Focus
   `currentForm.Focus()`
6. set the form.visible = false
   `currentForm.Visible = false;`
7. start to show the print dialog
   `printDialog.ShowDialog(currentForm)`
8. close the new form
   `currentForm.Close();`

   ```
      try
           {

             using (PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog())
               {
                   ReportPrintDocument rp = new ReportPrintDocument(rvPermit.ServerReport);

                   Form currentForm = new Form();
                   currentForm.Show();
                   currentForm.Activate();
                   currentForm.TopMost = true;
                   currentForm.Focus();
                   currentForm.Visible = false;

               if (printDialog.ShowDialog(currentForm) == DialogResult.OK)
               {
                   if (PrintReport != null)
                       PrintReport(this, e);

                   rp.PrinterSettings = printDialog.PrinterSettings;
                   rp.Print();
               }

               currentForm.Close();
           }
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           // Prevent any error while calling the printer dialog
       }
   ```